# Are you trying to add, update, or remove your email account?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft

For some time now, when I reboot my computer I get this message. Either if I click on Yes or No the popup closes and nothing happens. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-keeps-asking-are-you-sure-you-want-to-add/88097467-2db7-48b3-bac4-aea9f699bc54

Comment: You can use a tool like ProcExp to find the full running arguments for the process.

Answer (score 0):

Reason this comes up: using the windows mail App to add an account.
after adding my account this starts to pop up annoyingly many times.

fix: Go to the mail App and then right click that email account you are trying to add then go down to settings and then once the settings window comes delete that account and you are good to go!!

Comment: I don't have the Mail App install, yet this is appearing; this doesn't seem to be the solution. Especially when I'm getting this when booting up